# Create "grid" of polygons with the same 3D area based on an underlying raster variable (e.g. DTM height)

Tags: qgis, postgis, grass-gis, pyqgis

This could apply to point or raster values but imagine a raster of a continuous variable such as height (DTM). Is there a way to create a complete coverage of polygons that will have an equal area, taking into account the roughness of the underlying terrain? I realise that it would depend on where you seed the polygons (i.e. no unique solution) but if we accepted a certain degree of error it should be possible to do this with a nested regular grid (i.e. squares of differing fixed sizes)?

Comment: There is `ST_3DArea` function to calculate the area in 3d and that means yes, it is possible and it probably will take finite time. But what's the point of it? And why squares? It certainly will work much better with triangles.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "complete coverage of polygons" and "nested regular grid"? If these are sets of adjacent, non-overlapping polygons with areas as prescribed by the DTM, then your question seems equivalent to asking how to make an *anamorphosis* or [*equal-area cartogram.*](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=cartogram).